# Why is this code breaking on string input?

Tags: c++14

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
string flip();
int x;


int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    cout<<"Press 1 and enter"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    if(isalpha(x)==true){
            cout<<"int pls"<<endl;


    }
    else if(x==1){
        flip();
        cout<<"flipped"<<endl;


    }

    else if(x!=1){
        cout<<"try again"<<endl;
    }


    }
    system("pause>0");
    return 0;

}
string flip(){
    string ans;
    int y=rand()%2;
    if(y==0){
        string ans = "Heads";
            cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    else{
       string ans = "Tails";
     cout<<ans<<endl;
    }

    return ans;

}
```

whenever I put 2 instead of 1 it works and says try again but when i write some string like "fa"
the code closes instead of writing try again
if I change x to int and then if I try to input some string it just prints press 1 and enter 10 times instead of asking for an input again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of variable 'x'(=The argument of isalpha()) has to be char. If the type of 'x' is integer, the function(=isalpha()) recognizes 'x' as an ASCII value. How about trying this code?

```cpp
char x;


int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        cout<<"Press 1 and enter"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        if((bool)isalpha(x)==true){
            cout<<"int pls"<<endl;
        }
        else if(x=='1'){
            flip();
            cout<<"flipped"<<endl;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"try again"<<endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}
```